# Apply jQuery pagination on ajax in php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, pagination

I am using pagination and when I add products in cart it only works on 1st page.
When I click on 2nd page and try to add products to the cart, the ajax doesn't work.

How it will work on 2nd page too? Thanks in advance.

JavaScript code:

```
<script>
var monkeyList = new List('test-list', {
valueNames: ['name'],
page:9,
pagination: true

});
</script>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js">
 </script>

 <script>
 $(function(){
 $("#form").click(function(event){
 event.preventDefault();
 $.ajax({
 url:'<?php echo base_url().'cart/add/';?>',
 type:'POST',
 async: false,
 data:$(this).serialize(),
 success:function(result){

 $('#response').load('<?php echo base_url().'Products/menu';?>');
 }
 });
 });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Did you check in chrome developer tools whether the ajax request is being generated when you click  on 2nd page? And also see if you are getting any server errors in response tab.

Comment: can you pls add the html of #form tag #response tag

Answer (score 1):

You will have to bind click event to all the products in each page. Your code 
will bind the click event to products on current page only.

```
$(function(){
 $("#form").click(function(event){
 event.preventDefault();
 $.ajax({
 url:'<?php echo base_url().'cart/add/';?>',
 type:'POST',
 async: false,
 data:$(this).serialize(),
 success:function(result){

 $('#response').load('<?php echo base_url().'Products/menu';?>');
 }
 });
 });
});
```

Since the products in other pages will be hidden,it will not be in scope of selector $("#form"). And thus cannot bind click event to all.

You can add the eventlistener to the function and call the function on page change.

```
function AddToCart(){
$("#form").click(function(event){
 event.preventDefault();
 $.ajax({
 url:'<?php echo base_url().'cart/add/';?>',
 type:'POST',
 async: false,
 data:$(this).serialize(),
 success:function(result){

 $('#response').load('<?php echo base_url().'Products/menu';?>');
 }
 });
 });
}
```

$(function(){AddToCart();}
and similarly you can call this function on page change